# MongoDB 2.4.10 GroupBy

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, mongodb-query

I have created a MongoDB on my computer with MongoDB v3.4.4 and now I want to migrate to a Raspberry Pi and MongoDB (v 2.4.10), but when I want to execute this query it doesn't work because of the version.

```
db.product.aggregate(
{
    "$project": {
        "price": 1,
        "y": {
            "$year": "$date"
        },
        "m": {
            "$month": "$date"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": "$y",
            "month": "$m"
        },
        "total": {
            "$sum": "$price"
        },
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "_id.year": 1,
        "_id.month": 1
    }
})
```

Is there a way to translate this query to MongoDB 2.4.10?

The error is this:

[image: MongoDB Error]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specific error message are you getting? What driver/application and version are you using to run the query on your Pi? You don't appear to be using any newer aggregation operators so it isn't clear what the issue is. Note: you are sorting by a non-existent field `_id.day`  (which shouldn't cause an error, but won't affect your `$sort` outcome)

Comment: Thanks @Stennie, I updated the post with more information.

Comment: It looks like you are using a version of Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) which embeds a much newer version of the `mongo` shell. MongoDB 2.4 was first released in 2013 and reached end of life in October, 2016. Tools and drivers no longer need to test or support MongoDB 2.4 so you will probably have more success with driver/tool versions from that era. The easiest fix would be to use a `mongo` 2.4 shell version to connect to the server on your Pi.  Alternatively you could use an older version of Robomongo (eg. 0.8.5, which embeds the `mongo` 2.2 shell).